# How can I mock a container-provided object (e.g HttpSession) when Unit testing a GWT app?

Tags: unit-testing, gwt, mocking, junit4, httpsession

I am currently trying to unit test my Service layer (all *Impl.java classes) in a GWT app. Well the problem is that in the code, I have a dependency which targets an object provided by the Httpsession. Actually, I'm storing a User object (the currently logged in user) in the httpSession.

In order to get it back from the HttpSession (in the *Impl.java class), I am using this :

> **User user = ServiceUtil.getUser(getThreadLocalRequest().getSession());**

How can I mock this object from my Unit test code ?

thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

In the JUnit test case you can write

```
    HttpSession session = new MockHttpSession();
```

Where `MockHttpSession` is [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpSession.html)

You can put your user object in this session and then execute your test case.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you change the structure of your application so that the service layer doesn't depend on such things as a session (context agnostic) but instead the methods which need a user object of some kind get it injected (via parameter or however). So actually you include a very thin presentation layer (or however you may call it) which handles things such as responding to HTTP requests, logging a user in and putting the user object in the session and just calls service layer methods.

That way you can mock your user object in the unit test, pass it to your service layer and don't need any mock framework.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response,
I will try to change the arch according to your recommandations ...